# Haskell: Making Snap and LevelDB play nice

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-snap-framework, leveldb

I am using the LevelDB library and Snap framework together. I have:

```
main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ do
    db <- open "thedb" defaultOptions { createIfMissing = True }
    liftIO $ serveSnaplet defaultConfig $ initWeb db
```

Now in my handler, I'm unsure how to get back to `MonadResource IO` in order to query the database:

```
handleWords :: Handler App App ()
handleWords = do
    words <- uses thedb $ \db -> $ get db def "words"
    writeBS $ pack $ show words
```

Which gives me a: `No instance for (MonadResource IO) arising from a use of 'get'`

Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something about how to properly create a monad "stack". Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MonadResource`/`ResourceT` is one way of acquiring scarce resources in a way that guarantees resources will be freed in the case of an exception. Another approach is the `bracket` pattern, which is supported by Snap via [the `bracketSnap` function](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/snap-core/Snap-Core.html#v%3abracketSnap). You can use this to create the `ResourceT` context needed by LevelDB:

```
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Resource as Res
bracketSnap Res.createInternalState Res.closeInternalState $ \resState -> do
    let openAction = open "thedb" defaultOptions { createIfMissing = True }
    db <- Res.runInternalState openAction resState
```

This could be made simpler with some changes in Snap and leveldb:

- Instead of only providing the `open` function, which presumes a `MonadResource` context, there could be a function which returns a [`Resource` value](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-0.4.10/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#g:11). I'm making this tweak in persistent for the 2.0 release.
- Snap could provide support for either `MonadResource` or the `Resource` monad (two separate concepts with unfortunately similar names).

Answer (score 0):

Snap doesn't need to support MonadResource or Resource for you to do this.  You're doing the monad transformer composition in the wrong direction.  A look at the types will help.

```
serveSnaplet :: Config Snap AppConfig -> SnapletInit b b -> IO ()
runResourceT :: MonadBaseControl IO m => ResourceT m a -> m a
```

So you're trying to put an IO in the place that a ResourceT is expected.  You should approach this the other way around.  Put your `open "thedb" ...` call inside your application's Initializer with a liftIO.  But `open` is a MonadResource, so you need to use the ResourceT instance to get it into an IO.  It will look something like this:

```
app = makeSnaplet "app" "An snaplet example application." Nothing $ do
    ...
    db <- liftIO $ runResourceT $ open "thedb" defaultOptions
```

Then store the db handle in your App state and you can retrieve it later using `Handler`'s MonadReader or MonadState instances.

Comment: No, that will not work. The `db` will be immediately closed since you've exited the `runResourceT` block. The code you propose is similar to `withFile "foo" ReadMode return`.

Comment: Ahhh, right.  I'm used to using that pattern in other situations and forgot that runResourceT forces the cleanup.